# 'NSUnknownKeyException' setValue:forUndefinedKey: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key XXX.'

Tags: ios, objective-c, master-detail, xcode4.6

i've got a probleme with an `UISlider` in a `Master-detail application` :

I've put my slider on the detail view, and I've link it into `DetailViewController.h`, and i let it empty into `DetailViewController.m`.

So i've got in DetailViewController.h :

```
- (IBAction)mySlider:(id)sender;
```

and in DetailViewController.m :

```
- (IBAction)mySlider:(id)sender {}
```

When i try to compilate, i've got this exception :

```
'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<DetailViewController 0x754d490> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mySlider.'
```

Do you know why?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you setting the key ??

Comment: Please search for the error. There are countless existing questions that cover that error. Many are listed under the Related section of this question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: This is no compilation error, but a run-time error.

Secondly: Anywhere you used the mySlider. You can use keys for properties (not necessarily declared ones). But mySlider is an action (aka method).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I had connections in my view to objects that no longer existed. Try going to the connections inspector for your view in storyboard, (little right arrow in the top right of the screen) and seeing if there are any connections to objects that you might have deleted or changed the names of.